# UNet Client Disconnect Error: CRCMismatch on NetworkClient.Connect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, crc

I need some real help with this. I'm not sure how to resolve the CRC mismatch error. All I'm trying to do is send a byte array from my client to my server and I'm getting this error :

> UNet Client Disconnect Error: CRCMismatch UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate()

I've been trying for over a month now to connect the dots and get networking to correctly operate, but every step forward I take, leads to five steps back. I've been basically going in circles, I've done every unity networking tutorial that exists and I'm still so lost. I really need help resolving this. Could someone please help me with this? I've also attached the full code below. Thank you in advance!

**Client-side**

```
public class Client : NetworkBehaviour {

NetworkClient client = new NetworkClient();

private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 100;

private string serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
private int port = 5708;
private int hostId;
private int webHostId;
private int reliableChannel;
private int reliableSeqChannel;
private int reliableFragChannel;
private int unreliableChannel;
private int unreliableSeqChannel;

private string playerName;
private int connectionId;
private float connectionTime;
private bool isStarted = false;
private bool isConnected = false;
private bool readyToSendMsg = false;
private byte error;

private GameObject infoDisplayText;

public Texture2D texToSend;
string typeToSend = "Deer";
string idToSend = "1";
int strengthToSend = 80;
int hitPointsToSend = 2;

private string GetPlayerName()
{
    switch (Network.player.ipAddress.ToString())
    {
        case "192.168.1.160":
            playerName = "SMO Server";
            break;

        case "192.168.1.161":
            playerName = "SMO Client 1";
            break;

        case "192.168.1.162":
            playerName = "SMO Client 2";
            break;

        case "192.168.1.163":
            playerName = "SMO Client 3";
            break;

        case "192.168.1.164":
            playerName = "SMO Client 4";
            break;

        default:
            playerName = "SMO UNREG";
            break;
    }
    return playerName;
}

private void Start()
{
    infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");

    client.RegisterHandler(AnimalDataMsgType.SYSTEM_CONNECT, OnConnected);
    client.RegisterHandler(AnimalDataMsgType.SYSTEM_DISCONNECT, OnDisconnected);
    client.RegisterHandler(AnimalDataMsgType.SYSTEM_ERROR, OnError);

    client.Connect(serverIP, port);
}

public void Connect()
{
    string pName = GetPlayerName();

    if (pName == "")
        return;

    playerName = pName;

    NetworkTransport.Init();

    ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

    reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
    reliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableSequenced);
    reliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableFragmented);
    unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
    unreliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableSequenced);
    cc.PacketSize = 1440;
    cc.FragmentSize = 900;
    cc.ResendTimeout = 1000;
    cc.DisconnectTimeout = 5000;
    cc.ConnectTimeout = 1000;
    cc.MaxConnectionAttempt = 5;

    HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

    hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, 0);

    // Run client/server on different machines
    //hostID = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);  

    connectionId = NetworkTransport.Connect(hostId, serverIP, port, 0, out error);

    infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");
    infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += playerName + " connected.\n";

    connectionTime = Time.time;
    isConnected = true;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (!isConnected)
        return;

    int recHostId, connectionId, channelId;
    byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    int dataSize;
    byte error;

    NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

    switch (recData)
    {
        case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
            Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + " has connected");
            infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Connected to Server.\n";
            break;
    }
}

public void SendOnButtonPress()
{
    if (readyToSendMsg == true)
        SendTexture(texToSend, typeToSend, idToSend, strengthToSend, hitPointsToSend);
}

//Call to send the Texture and a simple string message
public void SendTexture(Texture2D tex, string type, string id, int strength, int hitpoints)
{
    AnimalData animalData = new AnimalData();

    animalData.Tex = tex.GetRawTextureData();
    animalData.Type = type;
    animalData.Id = id;
    animalData.Strength = strength;
    animalData.Hitpoints = hitpoints;

    client.Send(AnimalDataMsgType.animalData, animalData);
}

private void OnConnected(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    readyToSendMsg = true;
    Debug.Log("Connected to server");
}

private void OnDisconnected(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    readyToSendMsg = false;
    Debug.Log("Disconnected from server");
}

private void OnError(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    //SystemErrorMessage errorMsg = reader.SmartRead<SystemErrorMessage>();
    // Debug.Log("Error connecting with code " + errorMsg.errorCode);
    Debug.Log("Error connecting.");
}
```

**Server-side**

```
public class Server : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 100;
    private int port = 5708;
    private int hostId;
    private int webHostId;
    private int reliableChannel;
    private int reliableSeqChannel;
    private int reliableFragChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;
    private int unreliableSeqChannel;

    private bool isStarted = false;
    private byte error;

    private GameObject infoDisplayText;

    private void Awake()
    {
        infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        NetworkTransport.Init();

        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        reliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableSequenced);
        reliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableFragmented);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
        unreliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableSequenced);

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

        hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);

        if (NetworkTransport.IsStarted)
        {
            isStarted = true;
            Debug.Log("NetworkTransport is Started.");
            infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "NetworkTransport is Started.\n";
        }

        Debug.Log("Server Started.");
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Server Started.\n";

        setupRegisterHandler();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isStarted)
            return;

        int recHostId, connectionId, channelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;

        NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

        switch (recData)
        {
            case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
                Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + " has connected");
                infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Player " + connectionId + " has connected\n";
                break;
        }
    }

    // Create a client and connect to the server port
    public void setupRegisterHandler()
    {
        NetworkServer.Listen(port);
        Debug.Log("Registering server callbacks");
        NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(AnimalDataMsgType.animalData, OnTextureReceive);
    }

    //Called when texture is received
    public void OnTextureReceive(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        AnimalData animalData = netMsg.ReadMessage<AnimalData>();

        string type = animalData.Type;
        Debug.Log("Type : " + type);

        string id = animalData.Id;
        Debug.Log("ID : " + id);

        int strength = animalData.Strength;
        Debug.Log("Strength : " + strength);

        int hitpoints = animalData.Hitpoints;
        Debug.Log("Hit Points : " + hitpoints);

        //Your Received Texture2D
        Texture2D receivedtexture = new Texture2D(1280, 1024);
        receivedtexture.LoadRawTextureData(animalData.Tex);
        receivedtexture.Apply();

        Debug.Log(type + " data received!");
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += type + " data received!\n";
    }
}
```

**AnimalDataMsgType class**

```
    public class AnimalDataMsgType
{
    public static short animalData = MsgType.Highest + 1;
    public static short SYSTEM_CONNECT = MsgType.Connect;
    public static short SYSTEM_DISCONNECT = MsgType.Disconnect;
    public static short SYSTEM_ERROR = MsgType.Error;
}
```

**AnimalData class**

```
public class AnimalData : MessageBase
{
    public byte[] Tex;      // data coming from CanvasController
    public string Type;     // data coming from CanvasController
    public string Id;       // data coming from GameManager
    public int Strength;    // data coming from PlayerController
    public int Hitpoints;   // data coming from PlayerController
    public bool IsAlive;    // data coming from PlayerController
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the AnimalDataMsgType and AnimalData classes too? So, that I can try to figure it out?

Comment: @ZayedUpal I've just added those classes at the end of the post

Comment: The HLAPI CRC is a hash of the known NetworkBehaviour scripts and the channels that they use (with the NetworkSettingsAttribute). Yes, it is intended to occur if two different (and incompatible) Unity projects, or versions of the same project, talk to each other. 

Try to rebuild your application (or applications, if client and server are separate). It may cause if you change some networking code, and forget to rebuild.

Comment: @greyBow can you give a screenshot of your project window with Server game object selected? How are you managing the NetworkManager?

Comment: @SergiyKlimkov that makes sense. So both client and server are in the same Unity project. From my Connect function in my client script I'm doing my initialization and initial connect to my server and on the server side I'm starting up my server immediately in Start function. That connection event is successful. If that one is successful, what would be making my` client.Connect(serverIP, port);` fail? Do I need to create a new ConnectionConfig for that connection? I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adding `client.Configure(cc, 1);` right before `client.Connect(serverIP, port);`. The problem was my NetworkClient client connectionConfig profile need to be set to the same config settings defined in my NetworkTransport HostTopology and without setting a connectionConfig to my client.Connect function it was causing the CRC mismatch. Also when sending a message after creating my NetworkClient instance I use `client.SendByChannel` so I can set my channelId.

Answer (score 0):

Some or all of the ConnectionConfig values must match on host and on clients. Had the same issue when I specified different DisconnectTimeout values.